# Integral with quadratic square root inside trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, probability-limit-theorems

Is there anyway to solve $\displaystyle \int t \frac{\sin \left(\frac{t}{2} \sqrt{ a \left(t+ \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}}\right) }{ \sqrt{  a \left(t+ \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}}}  \operatorname{d}t \tag8$ either by analytical method or from geometrical method with out using numerical methods? means looking for a closed form with out infinite series expansion in the result

NB: Main issue is the lack of general form

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the radical can be simplified to $\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}$

Now Integrate by Parts  $\displaystyle\int t\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}2\right)}{\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}\ dt$

$\displaystyle=t\int\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}2\right)}{\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}\ dt-\int\left[\frac{d(t)}{dt}\int\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}2\right)}{\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}\ dt\right]dt \tag 1$ is the result of Integration by Parts

and for $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}2\right)}{\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}\ dt,$  set  $t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}=2u$ to find something really interesting

Comment: It looks OK for the first line but not for the second. Typo's, I presume. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Thanks for your observation

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Sir,have you made typo error changed? Thanks

Comment: @Rejo_Slash, Could you follow the steps?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes I do .. I added the missing $\int$ . Now I am on $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}2\right)}{\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}\ dt,$ . I didnt get a closed form..I   keep trying

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $\mathbf{{\color{Red} \int\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}2\right)}{\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}\ dt =4\int \frac{sin(u) }{4at^2+3bt+2c}\ du } }$ After the substitution u mentioned, I got this. You can see I was not able to convert all t to u