# Square root till infinity

Tags: nested-radicals

What is the value of $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{ x + \cdots } } }\,$?  I know the basic trick to calculate this using $f = \sqrt{ x + f }$. But, I want more accurate answer which is I am not getting with this formula.

Answer (score 5):

Squaring we get $f^2=x+f\iff f^2-f-x=0\implies f=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}2$

Now as $f>0,$ discard the negative root assuming $x>0$

Comment: Reaching 100k! Congrats!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Thanks. How to discard $$\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4x}}2$$ if $x<0$?

Comment: Hey lab ! Congratulations

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Thanks. Could you please have another look into http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938585/integral-with-quadratic-square-root-inside-trigonometric-functions/938589#938589 ?

Comment: I did but may I confess that I do not see how you finish !

Answer (score 0):

If $f=\sqrt{x+f}$ then $f^2-f-x=0$, hence
$$f=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}.$$